# Stripping commas from Integers or decimals in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a gsub equivalent for integers or decimals? Should gsub work with integers? Basically I'm just trying to enter decimal into a ruby form and what the user to be able to use commas. For example, I want the user to be able to enter 1,000.99.

I've tried using

```
before_save :strip_commas

def strip_commas
    self.number = self.number.gsub(",", "")    
end
```

but get the following error "undefined method `gsub' for 8:Fixnum" where "8" is replaced with whatever number the user enters.

Comment: is the number field a float? Rails should take care of the conversion for you so the comma won't really be there in the data.

Comment: The field is decimal. When I enter something like 2,000 into the field, I get "2" in my mysql database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your field is a Fixnum, it will never have commas, as Rails will have to convert the user input into a number in order to store it there.

However, it will do that by calling to_i on the input string, which is not what you want.
overriding the normal setter to something like

```
def price=(num)
  num.gsub!(',','') if num.is_a?(String)
  self[:price] = num.to_i
end
```

Not tested, but something resembling this should work...

You need to get at the commas while the input is still a string.

**Edit:**
As noted in comments, if you want to accept decimals, and create something not an integer, you need a different conversion than `String.to_i`.  Also, different countries have different conventions for numeric punctuation, so this isn't a complete solution.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I just need to change to_i to to_d since. I was going insane due to the lack of commas in a Fixnum. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot you also wanted to allow decimals and we're dealing with Fixnum and not Integer... But you got the idea.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Be aware that this might catch you out somewhere down the line, since Europeans will type things like 100,00, meaning 100.00, which you'll interpret as 10000.  I speak from experience.

Comment: Luckily, the users will all be US based. At least for this app. In the future though, is there a better way to do this that is more region agnostic?

Comment: great answer! `self[:price]  = num.to_f` is correct way.  I tried `self.price = num.to_f` it raises `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)`

Comment: Will this return nil if the variable (num in this example) doesn't contain a comma? What if the user just enters 100? Would the result be nil?

Answer (score 3):

try `self.number.gsub(/\D/, '')`. That is, remove everything that isn't a digit. Regexen make no distinction between integers, floats, decimals, etc. It's all strings. And Rails won't convert it correctly for you, because it just calls `#to_i` or `#to_f` on it.

EDIT:

actually: `self.number.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_f`: everything that isn't a digit or decimal point, and convert it to a float.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `'.'` because, when it is in a range `'[.]'`, it loses its specialness and is automatically a literal. So `[^\d.]` is more correct. Leaving it escaped is OK though because it acts as a visual reminder of the behavior.