# Allowing commas in a numerical field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is such a dumb question that I feel like I must be missing something simple. I have a form with a `quantity` field. People keep typing commas when they enter the quantity (for example, they type `12,000` to indicate twelve thousand) so I would like to strip out the commas before saving the quantity (`12000` in the example) into an integer column in the database.

So far I have tried two methods. Overriding the setter method as suggested [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6541864/574190)

```
  def quantity=(num)
    num.gsub!(',', '') if num.is_a?(String)
    self[:quantity] = num.to_i
  end
```

This works in a sense. If I type `12,000` in the quantity field and submit the form, I get `12000` in the database. The problem is that it also bypasses all `quantity` validations. No longer can I validate the presence of a value for quantity for example. This is not good.

I have also tried to use a before validation callback (instead of overriding the setter):

```
  before_validation :sanitize_quantity

  def sanitize_quantity
    # Doesn't wok because quantity.to_i already called by this point.
  end
```

This doesn't work because by the time the quantity has reached the callback method, Rails has already called `to_i` on it. This means that `12,000` will be truncated to `12` by the time it reaches the callback. Once again, not good.

What else can I try aside from stripping the commas on the client-side?

As a final note, I am aware that this is essentially a dumb thing to do because certain countries use periods and commas in different ways. I still need to do it anyway.

Comment: It does not make sense to me. Are you using `update_attributes` in the controller? your setter (the first thing that is executed) transforms "12,000" into 12000, so that should be the value that "sanitize_quantity" gets. Did you set a breakpoint at that point and saw 12 instead?

Comment: Sorry, my wording is a little confusing. I tried the two methods at different times. At no point did I have a callback and an overridden setter method at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually figured this out just as I was reading over my question.

The key is to use a virtual attribute.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  def flexible_quantity
    quantity
  end

  def flexible_quantity=(quantity)
    self.quantity = quantity.gsub(',', '') unless quantity.blank?
  end
 end
```

Then in the form, use the virtual attribute.

```
<%= f.text_field :flexible_quantity %>
```

Now validate the presence of the flexible_quantity value instead.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :flexible_quantity, presence: true

  # The cool this is that we can leave the numericality validation on the quantity field.
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Use Type Coercions

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to coerce strings into numbers. If so, you can just use an explicit cast like so:

```
validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: true

def quantity=(num)
  self[:quantity] = num.to_s.scan(/\b-?[\d.]+/).join.to_f
end
```

#### Tests and Examples

See see how this works, you can try the following at the console.

```
# String as input.
number = '12,956.05'
number.to_s.scan(/\b-?[\d.]+/).join.to_f
=> 12956.05

# Float as input.
number = 12956.05
number.to_s.scan(/\b-?[\d.]+/).join.to_f
=> 12956.05

# Using an ActiveRecord object.
q = Quantity.new quantity: '12,956.05'
=> #<Quantity id: nil, quantity: 12956.05, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
q.save
=> true
```

Comment: Will this not suffer from the issue that I mentioned in my question? Overriding the `quantity=()` method causes quantity validations such as `validates :quantity, presence: true` to be skipped.

Comment: @DavidTuite Actually, I tested my example above and it works fine. The only thing I did differently is to explicitly change the validation to `validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: true` so that it also allows Float, which my example requires. So, "It works for me (tm)" but you could certainly change the casts to #to_i instead of #to_f if you only want integers.

Comment: @DavidTuite The validation isn't being bypassed. The issue is that an explicit cast will *always* ensure numericality, so `q.quantity = 'foo'` will be cast as `0.0` and pass the validation because `q.valid?` will always be true. You may need some additional tests or a custom validator if this causes you grief.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the quantity in `params[:quanity]`. You can just call a helper method (defined in your controller, for instance) to fix the String, and then pass that along to your model.

```
# YourController.rb
def create # or whatever
    quantity = sanitize_quantity(params[:quantity])
    YourModel.create!(:quantity => quantity)
end

private

    def sanitize_quantity(num)
        num.gsub!(',', '') if num.is_a?(String)
        return num.to_i
    end
```

So you sanitize it **before** it goes to your model, so it can still have validations done on it.

Comment: Note: nil.to_i is 0. You may want to guard around that, or not.

Comment: Having the controller be responsible for this seems like a bad idea. It should properly be handled by the model.

Comment: You can throw it anywhere. I just did it in the controller for the example's sake. Personally, I prefer to have an upsert method where extra work like this can be done: `YourModel.upsert(params)` and then in the model code the sanitizing would happen.